# Using a template structure as a namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, namespaces, using

I just finished an iteration on a library that I am writing. 
In order to isolate certain types, I originally put them into a namespace.
Then, I realised that this namespace should actually be templated, so I turned it into a struct, ie:

```
namespace A
{
    typedef _foo foo;
}
```

became

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
    typedef _foo<T> foo;
};
```

This was more convenient to use in say, this situation:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    typedef A<T>               nsA;
    typedef typename nsA::foo  foo_type;
};
```

Now, I'm using that library in another library, and there, I know that the template type `T` will never change. So I would like to do something like:

```
namespace B
{
    using namespace A<double>;
}
```

but obviously, this doesn't work. Of course, I could just stop being lazy, and `typedef` manually each definition in `A<double>`, but I like being lazy when I can. Any thoughts on how to do something equivalent to this last step?

Comment: In c++11, you may alias all your template: `namespace A { template <typename T> using foo = _foo<T>; }` and then in `MyClass`: `using foo_type = A::foo<T>;` (you repeat `T` but get rid of `typename`). That doesn't solve your fixed parameter btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I just found the answer. Sorry, if you think this question was useless, I'll delete it, just let me know in comment.

Since I used a struct as a namespace in the first place, the solution is to keep using a struct as a namespace (!):

```
struct B
    : public A<double>
{};
```

Here is a [demo](http://cpp.sh/4pep).

Comment: BTW, inheritance is `public` by default with `struct`, so you may simplify to `struct B : A<double> {};`.